# Parse XML in oracle when same dom structure is repeated multiple time's

Tags: oracle, xml-parsing, oracle-xml-db

I know how to parse an xml in oracle  which goes something like this

```
select extractvalue(column_value, 'CIRS/CIR/@applicantId') applicantId
into applicantId
 from CIBIL_BINARY_INPUT ,table(xmlsequence(xmltype(ded_enq_xml)))
```

Now i have an xml as shown below

```
<library>
    <book>
    <name>Harry potter</name>
    <author>Harry potter</author>
    </book>
    <book>
    <name> watson </name>
    <author>Harry watson </author>
    </book>
    <book>
    <name> john </name>
    <author> potter</author>
    </book>
    </library>
```

As you can see the book node is repeated multiple times

How can i extract it so that i can insert it as 3 different 'book' rows in my `library` table.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your first problem is to extract multiple books from xml. This can be solved like this:

```
select
    extractvalue(column_value, '/book/name') name,
    extractvalue(column_value, '/book/author') author
from
  table(xmlsequence(extract(xmltype('<library><book>...</book><book>...</book>...</library>'), '/library/book')));
```

Hope this helps.